# Identification of endo and exo products in this Diels-Alder reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, pericyclic

This synthesis example is shown in the book *Cycloaddition Reactions in Organic Synthesis* by  S. Kobayashi and K. A. Jorgensen ([link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/3527600256)), on p. 15:

[image]

**8** is a chiral catalyst, which can be ignored, in the context of my question. The product shown is the *exo* product. However, I am unable to understand or visualise why it is the *exo* product. It does not seem apparent to me that the transition state leading to this product would have the aldehyde group being further away from the $\pi$ system of electrons. I would greatly appreciate assistance in helping me understand this.

Comment: [This post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131628/cis-trans-diene-reacting-with-trans-dienophile-in-d-a-reaction/131675#131675) on the DA reaction may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The product you have drawn looks like an *exo*-product. Conformation **1** leads to an *exo*-transition state that produces exo **2** as the enantiomer shown. With an achiral catalyst *ent-exo* **2** would also be formed as a racemic pair. To obtain the racemic *endo* product, flip the diene 180<sup>o</sup> in conformation **1** to obtain *endo* **2**. For the enantiomer, flip the unsaturated aldehyde 180<sup>o</sup>. If you have access to the literature, research papers by Herbert House or William Roush<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00412a027)</sup> on this type of Diels-Alder reaction. I believe they saw *trans*-fusions (*endo* products) for the ring system.

[image]

**Addendum:** (12/7/2022)

It is likely that the formation of the *exo*-product you cite is a typographical error.
In this example,<sup>[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol1019103)</sup> a chiral ruthenium catalyst forms the *endo*-product, which has the *trans*-fusion.

[image]

**Reference:**

1. Roush, W. R.; Peseckis, S. M. Intramolecular Diels-Alder reactions: the angularly methylated trans-perhydroindan ring system. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1981**, *103*, 6696-6704; [doi 10.1021/ja00412a027](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00412a027).
2. Thamapipol, S.; Bernardinelli, G.; Besnard, C.; Kundig, E. P. Chiral Ruthenium Acid Catalyzed Intramolecular Diels-Alder Reactions. *Org. Lett.* **2010**, *12, 24,* 5604-5607; [doi 10.1021/ol1019103](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol1019103)

Comment: @Buttonwood: Thanks for the fix. The hour was getting late. ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the product shown is in fact the *exo* product. I have made the necessary edits to my question.

Comment: Though not part of every citation style, I perceive the provision of a more complete set of bibliographic data -- doi to get to the landing page of the publication *plus* indication of the title of the article -- as helpful for learning. In this regard (my point of view) chemistry.se benefits from the pattern equally seen e.g., on [Master Organic Chemistry](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/) ([example](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/01/31/the-gabriel-synthesis/)), or papers in *J.Chem. Educ.* ([example](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361)).

Comment: With the [Chemistry Reference Resolver](https://chemsearch.kovsky.net/) living in the browser, it often only is a single click to eventually get to a place to collect the missing data, too.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the most foolproof way to identify the *endo* and *exo* products is to look at the stereochemistry in the product. Consider first a standard intermolecular Diels–Alder reaction:

[image: Endo Diels–Alder]

I labelled the substituents on the diene $\mathrm{R^t}$ and $\mathrm{R^c}$, for *trans* and *cis* respectively, to describe their position with respect to the single bond in the middle of the diene.

What we can see from this is that the *endo* product has the electron-withdrawing group (EWG) placed *cis* to $\mathrm{R^t}$ (and *trans* to $\mathrm{R^c}$). (OK, sorry, the naming is a bit confusing; but I'm sure you can make sense of it.) The opposite would be true of the *exo* product: in that case, the EWG would be *cis* to $\mathrm{R^c}$ (and *trans* to $\mathrm{R^t}$).

The intramolecular case is harder to draw a transition state for (user55119 has done it nicely!), but this doesn't change the conclusion drawn above. In your case, the diene only has a single substituent which is of the $\mathrm{R^t}$ type (the substituted double bond is *trans* configured). This substituent ends up becoming the five-membered ring:

[image: Diels–Alder stereochemistry identification]

It is quite clear from the final product that the EWG is *trans* to the $\mathrm{R^t}$ substituent. So, in agreement with user55119's analysis, the product shown is actually *exo*.

Comment: "What we can see from this is that the endo product has the electron-withdrawing group (EWG) placed *cis* to $\ce {R_t}$ (and trans to $\ce {R_c}$)." Is this just like a statement of fact or is there supposed to be an explanation too as to why it is like that? Is it supposed to be explained by the orientation of the groups in the transition state?

Comment: @TanYongBoon That's a literal description of the stereochemistry in the product, which in turn follows from the transition state.

Comment: So I can imagine the two $\ce {R_c}$ groups to be like a methylene group in cyclopentadiene and hence, we always see the methylene bridge above the 6-membered ring formed in the DA reactions of cyclopentadiene? I am just trying to find some way to help myself remember this. Is what I suggested regarding cyclopentadiene and the relation to the $\ce {R_c}$ groups correct?

Comment: Also, what if $\ce {R_c = R_t = H}$?

Comment: @TanYongBoon First comment: In cyclopentadiene, yes, the CH2 group would take the place of R_c. When drawn *in this way*, then yes, the bridge will always end up "above" the 6-membered ring. However, that's not necessarily true, because if the dienophile approaches from *above* the diene rather than below as I've drawn, then the bridge will actually end up *below* the six-membered ring. That, therefore, isn't a reliable way to remember this. What **is** reliable is the relative stereochemistry between the EWG and the groups. Regardless of where the dienophile approaches from, [...]

Comment: [...] the endo product will **always** have the EWG trans to R_c, i.e., the EWG is opposite the methylene bridge. Now, to be honest, I don't suggest memorising this at all. Why bother? You can draw it out whenever you need to. If you aren't comfortable with drawing out the TS of a D–A reaction and obtaining the stereochemistry from that, I'd strongly recommend getting better at that, before trying to look at more complicated examples. Understanding it is better than memorising odd mnemonics like mine. Lastly, if R_c = R_t, then there are no endo or exo diastereomers, there is only one product.

Comment: Is there a rotation of the $\ce {R_c}$ and $\ce {R_t}$ groups during the reaction? Certainly there must be a rotation from being in the plane of butadiene right? Wouldn't the orientation of the groups in the product depend on how the two groups rotate?

Comment: @TanYongBoon Yes, they have to rotate, but it's physically impossible to rotate "the other way". The moment the single bond is formed, the stereochemistry is fixed. You just need to "unfold" the six-membered ring, and there aren't two ways to go about it, there isn't any conrotatory/disrotatory thing going on here.

Comment: One last question, can I say that for the example reaction you have provided, whether the dienophile approaches from top or bottom, the endo product is the same?

Comment: To be absolutely honest, the rotation either way seems physically possible to me. So I am not able to understand why you say that the rotation in one of the directions is physically impossible

Comment: @TanYongBoon Whether the dienophile approaches from top or bottom affects which *enantiomer* you get. It doesn't affect which *diastereomer* you get, i.e. the relative stereochemistry, and that's what exo/endo are about, they are labels for diastereomers. The endo product will always be the same diastereomer, although in general you will get both enantiomers of it. I'm afraid, I cannot give you a tutorial on Diels–Alder stereochemistry. Please look it up in a textbook. It's an important enough topic that any decent textbook will cover it. I vaguely recall Clayden has a good section on this.

Comment: @TanYongBoon Maybe this might help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLxaf.jpg (1) Reactants. (2) The DA product. Note that I haven't dont any "rotation" of the groups yet; this is just what happens when you form the necessary bonds. (3) Same DA product but viewed from a different angle. (4) Rotated product / redrawn stereochemistry of the bottom carbon to match conventional chemical structures. At no point in this, is it possible for C and T to change places. In particular, before the reaction happens they can't interchange (double bond) and after the reaction happens the stereochem is fixed.